# Ubuntu gnome discontinued prematurely?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, 18.04, mate

After running ubuntu gnome for some years, I was happy to hear that mainline ubuntu was returning to gnome as the default. So I was eager to upgrade my trusty ubuntu gnome 16.04 desktop to ubuntu 18.04. Yikes. My impression is that they simply tried to implement the unity desktop using gnome 3 libraries. I'm not seeing a gnome 3 desktop here.

Disappointed, I reinstalled with ubuntu mate 18.04, and find it fairly nice. But what I really wanted was an up to date gnome 3 desktop running on ubuntu 18.04. Any hope of ever resurrecting the ubuntu gnome flavor?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is using Gnome desktop, but configured to be looking a bit like unity. You can always change it.

Comment: @Pilot6 Can you post an answer on how to make the Gnome desktop look more like Gnome and less like Unity? I would but I've never used Gnome DE.

Comment: I am not using 18.04. So it's not my problem ;-)

Comment: @pomsky Sounds good. I voted along :)

Comment: @pilot6 I'd also like to see such a guide. It was absolutely not apparent from poking around. I also observed that it could not handle folders on the desktop. I suppose that's also configurable with some obscure gconf setting?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle folders on the desktop"?

Comment: Can you create folders on the desktop? If there are existing folders in ~/Desktop, what happens when you click on them? I found the results to be in violation of the principle of least astonishment